# How to plot a dataframe with columns of datetimes in a line graph?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, plot, series

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```py
Index      Andy           Bobby        Charlie
0          2019-01-02     2019-01-01   2019-01-15
1          2019-01-05     2019-01-04   2019-01-17
2          2019-01-06     2019-02-03   2019-02-14
...
103        2019-07-01     2019-06-03   NaT
104        2019-07-06     NaT          NaT
105        2019-07-23     NaT          NaT
```

The dates are when each person had a meeting with a client. I want to create a plot of line graphs that chart how many meetings each person had since year to date.

I'm having trouble with the plotting syntax, also the NaT values are making it tough to graph every column? New to Python so would appreciate any help, thank you.

It might be easier to transpose the dataframe such that the datetimes are the indices, but I am not too sure how to do that either.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through every column of your dataframe, drop the missing values with `dropna()`, reset the index (and add 1 = number of meetings) and plot it... like you correctly said with values and index reversed:

```
fig = plt.figure()
for c in df:
    person = df[c].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
    person.index = person.index+1
    plt.plot(person.values, person.index)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Number of Meetings')
```

[image]